# Count the number of saleable pairs of items

Tags: python

I want to optimize my code for following question:

> A company sells dumbbells in pairs. These are weights for exercising. They receive a shipment of dumbbells weighing anywhere from 1 unit up to a certain maximum.
>
> A pair can only be sold if their weights are sufficiently close: no greater than 1 unit difference.
>
> Given an inventory of various weights, determine the maximum number of pairs the company can sell.
>
> For example, if there are 2 dumbbells of weight 1, 4 of weight 2, 3 of weight 3 and 1 of weight 4, (arr = [2,4,3,1])
>
> they can be paired as [1,1], [2,2], [2,2], [3,3], [3,4] for a total of 5 pairs.
>
> i-th element is the number of dumbbells with a weight of i+1.

For example:

```
if arr  = [3,5,4,3]
number of pairs will be 7 as shown below: 
initial array is to be converted to  [3(1's),5(2's),4(3's),3(4's)] i.e [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4]
```

Now we need to make pairs like this `[1,1][1,2][2,2][2,2][3,3][3,3][4,4]` remaining last 4 is left as it is single.
So total number of pairs is 7.
Following is my solution for the same:

```
def taskOfPairing(arr):
    
    n = len(arr)
    count = 0
    newList = []
    
    for i, j in enumerate(arr):
        newList += [i + 1]*j
    print(newList) 
    count1 = 0
    k = 1
    newList.sort()
    n1 = len(newList)
    l=0
    r=0
    while r<n1:
        if newList[r]-newList[l] < k:
            count1 += 1
            newList.pop(l)
            newList.pop(r)
            n1 = len(newList)
            l=0
            r=0
            if len(newList) == 1:
                break
    return count1



arr= [3,5,4,3]
print(taskOfPairing(arr))
```

**output = 7**

My output works but only when there is small numbers in list like `arr = [3,5,4,3]` or `[2,4,3,1]`.

If I try putting large numbers in list for example, `arr = [100000,200000,300000,400000]` my code will not work and will cause a lot of delay in execution. Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong in this code. My apologies to stack overflow for asking naive questions.

Answer (score 6):

The task doesn't require to generate a list of pairs - just to count them. So:

- take as much 1-1 pairs as you can ('count += arr[0]//2');
- if one dumbbell is left ('arr[0]' is odd) and there are dumbbells of weight 2, increase count and reduce 'arr[1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)' by one;
- repeat the process for weights 2, 3 and so on.

Also, the sorting is excessive - just FYI.

Oh, and be sure to read [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and apply it to your code.